# How can I send a message to a channel inside a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to the channel id inside of config.LOG_CHANNEL
When I run the ping command I log const channel which is undefined and client.channels.cache is empty because of that

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'This is a ping command!',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('Pong');
        const fs = require('fs');
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const client = new Discord.Client();

        let config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(config.LOG_CHANNEL);
        console.log(channel);
        console.log(client.channels.cache);
    }
}
```

This is my console output:

```
undefined
Collection [Map] {}
```

Comment: Does `config` print what you expect it to?

Comment: @dwosk yes it does, and logging config.LOG_CHANNEL gives me the channel ID

Comment: are you using the new Discord v12 js?

Comment: @dwosk yes i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the channel id a snowflake id? if it still has the # or <> symbols it wont be able to get your channel.
ex.

```
        var channelID = config.LOG_CHANNEL.replace(/<|#|>/g, "") //strip snowflake id to reference channel directly
        var channel1 = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID)
```

Comment: Okay so i just tried this and this actually worked could u explain why? The id was allready saved whithout symbols

Comment: It was saved like this: "LOG_CHANNEL": "763386559164183100"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like channels aren't cached.
Try using this:

```
client.channels.fetch(config.LOG_CHANNEL);
```